# Split String into Array of Words to find Longest

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I am working on a task to search any given string for the longest word. I am thinking the ideal way to do this is to split the string into an array consisting of each word then looping through that array and comparing each length to return the longest. I am stuck on just separating the string into an array of words. The questions I have seen answered similar in topic seem to use much to complicated methods for such a simple task. I am looking for help on a beginner level as this is my first time incorporating regular expressions into my code.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
     str = str.toLowerCase().split("/\w+");
     return str;
}

findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');
```

Comment: Is your question "why doesn't my regex work"? Remove the slash, and double the backslash. Your regex is contained inside a Javascript string, so it does not need the initial slash but *does* need double backslashes.

Comment: @jongware after editing my regex to "\\w+" I am still getting the same error and I get an array featuring the entire string as my result

Comment: This is your first mention of an error. So ... what error?

Comment: I should have said 'unwanted result' not error. The answer was suggested lower on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findLongest(str){
    var array = str.split(" ");
    var longest = "";
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i].length > longest.length){
            longest = array[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(longest);
}
findLongest("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: `findLongest("Look at the regex break on this sentence, where it's important as to where the comma lies.");` >> `'sentence,'` - `'sentence'.length > 'important'.length` >> `false` - Super naive solutions are fun.

Comment: Just remove the punctuation before splitting the string :p

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is structured poorly. Even if it was fixed, `.split(/\w+/)`, splitting on the words would create an array with results *opposite* of what you are looking for.

You should be using [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to collect the words.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var match = '';

  str.match(/\w+/gi).forEach(function (w) {
    if (w.length > match.length) {
      match = w;
    }
  });
  
  return match;
}

var a = findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

console.log(a);
```

Still slightly naive, since words can have hyphens in the middle, and apostrophes on the front, in the middle, and on the end.

Comment: As I am reading through this my first thought is that the instructions of the task specifically indicate to use the split() function. Is there a way we can answer this question using the split function please? @oka

Comment: Split on the spaces `.split(' ')`, or `.split(/\s+/)`, but that's incredibly naive - what happens when your string has punctuation? `'hello world!'.split(/\s+/)` >> `["hello", "world!"]`

Comment: Again, this is an exercise designed for a beginner. For punctuation couldnt we use a replace function. So would the correct regex be .split(/\s+/g) ?

Comment: If this is for beginners, why should it be *more* complex? `.match` should be used to *match* substrings - `.split` should be used to *split* on substrings, which one seems more appropriate for matching words?

Comment: The task isn't to match words. Thank you for your help. However I think some other people are closer on track to what the task is asking specifically.

Comment: 'I am working on a task to search any given string for the longest word.' Huh.